# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined" using jQuery from content-script chrome extensions

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use jQuery to traverse the DOM of the page that I am injecting code into but keep getting this error.

My manifest file is:

```
{
  "name": "Jive enhancer",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48" : "sample-48.png",
    "128" : "sample-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],//just for the question
      "js": [
            "jquery-1.7.2.js",
                "contentscript.js"
                ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my contentscript.js:

```
function test () {
    console.log ("injected");
    $("j-comm-activity-list").style.left="100px";   
}

test();
```

The page that my contentscript is being injected into has a div with this id: "j-comm-activity-list", yet from some reason I keep getting this error.
Executing the same command from the console works just fine.  I am despearte!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery (Sizzle) selectors, just like in CSS, you signifiy an id with a `#`. The selector `$("j-comm-activity-list")` without a `#` is searching for an element with the tag name `j-comm-activity-list`, instead of an element with that id. You want to be using the [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

jQuery objects also do not have a `style` property. You can get the DOMElement you selected using array notation like `$("#j-comm-activity-list")[0]` (which is shorthand for`$("#j-comm-activity-list").get(0)`. But it's preferable that you use built in jQuery functions like [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("#j-comm-activity-list").css('left', 100);
```

Comment: Since your answer goes in so much detail, I may add that the `$("#j-comm-activity-list")[0]` notation is a shorthand for `$("#j-comm-activity-list").get(0)` and the `.css` may as well accept integer values which jquery automatically coverts to `px`: `.css('left', 100)` - I personally find it more readable and easier to type when doing calculations. +1

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You're right. It is much nicer to use a number with .css for `px` values. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#j-comm-activity-list").css('left', '100px')
```